# Claudia.js with multiple AWS lambda functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-architecture, claudiajs

I'm using claudia.js CLI to deploy functions and web API to AWS lambda and API gateway. 
My project files structure is as follow:

```
functions
--function1
---- node_modules
---- package.json
---- index.js
---- claudia.json
--function2
---- node_modules
---- package.json
---- index.js
---- claudia.json
```

The problem is that in order to update new version I have to run "claudia update" in every function folder...so I have to run it once for every function (in every folder). Is there a way to tell claudia.js to update all my functions at once?

Comment: Claudia can't update multiple functions out of the box. The question is if you really need to update all the functions at the same time? In most of the projects with multiple Lambda functions I worked on, functions were independent and I was deploying only the function I changed.
If you do need to update multiple functions at the same time you can create a script, to do that for you, or if you have a lot of functions it might make sense for you to use CloudFormation (Claudia doesn't support it).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than getting ClaudiaJS to do the work, use a tool to run ClaudiaJS.
Most monorepo tools will suffice, such as [Lerna](https://lernajs.io/) but there is gamont of less opinionated tools if you don't care for what Lerna offers - [Lolaus](https://gitlab.com/tom.davidson/lolaus) is pretty low-level.

With Lerna you would need to use the prescribed repo structure, get linked node_modules, and `lerna run deploy` would run the npm deploy script of each package that has it.

With Lolaus you would search for all of your functions and then run an arbitrary command in each directory: `lolaus "*/*/caudia.json" claudia update`

Answer (score 0):

We have a lambda repo with multiple replate lambdas, each in its own subfolder.

```
> lambdas 
> |_lambda1
> |___main.js
> |___main.spec.js
> |___claudia.json
> |___package.json
> |_lambda2
> |___main.js
> |___main.spec.js
> |___claudia.json
> |___package.json
> |_helpers
> |_test.sh
> |_deploy.sh
```

We use npm and a bash script to iterate over each lambda and run a consistent set of npm/eslint commands on them. If that passes the build process we run a claudia command the same way on each lambda. There is some cut and paste